# how to get the guid in Dynamic crm 4

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am writing a small project that can return some data entities from Dynamic crm4, however the retrieve method in OrganizationService class requires a Guid object, however I want to be able to pass the name of Data e.g(entity name= campaign, campaign name=test campaign), how can I get the Guid for the campaign by passing the campaign name.

Comment: google crm 4.0 retrievemultiple

Comment: Hi @GuidoPreite i couldn't find anything useful, most of the examples are for the latest versions of the Dynamic CRMs..

Comment: this is the first result when you google crm 4.0 retrievemultiple https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/765fee1d-9453-4090-ad85-7ea24e8480aa/retrievemultiple-using-dynamic-entity-ms-crm-40?forum=crmdevelopment looks useful to me

Comment: thank you very much @GuidoPreite for some reason my search engine didn't show me this results!!. this is exactly what I am looking for!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right answer in the link below:

```
https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/765fee1d-9453-4090-ad85-7ea24e8480aa/retrievemultiple-using-dynamic-entity-ms-crm-40?forum=crmdevelopment
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember CRM 4.0 SDK also have good samples for every request, so if you have not checked that yet, download SDK from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38